# Find profile view when having frontal and top views

Tags: technical-drawing, autocad, drawings

I need to find profile view of an drawing when I have frontal and top views.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Transistor, I updated and added photo of what I've done so far.

Comment: So what about the base?

Comment: 1) All you've done is create the construction lines that will allow you to finish. 2) What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: I need help in finishing the profile view and i'm not sure if I used correct lines

Comment: Apply solid lines to all the lines visible from the new viewpoint. Apply dashed lines to the hidden lines.

Comment: You should also include the hidden diamond in the bottom drawing (called the TOP (square 44)).

Comment: @Transistor Sorry for undermining your and other's attempts to help OP. Thanks for pointing out. It won’t happen again. I deleted my answer.